# What is the real bodyscape photography concept?

Tags: shadows, low-key, nude-photography

I had my first experience in bodyscape photography using lights. I created two versions of a photo retouched by Lightroom. Through your experience I would like to know what makes a real bodyscape photo? Which one of my two versions captures the real concept of bodyscape photography?

*(I also posted the same question on Nikonites site but have not had any feedback or critique.)*

Warning: the images are potentially NSFW. Hover over them to reveal.

Version 1:

> [image: Version 1]

Version 2:

> [image: Version 2]

Answer (score 10):

> Which one of my two versions captures the real concept of bodyscape photography?

I would have to say neither, since both images are instantly recognizable as a female nude with very little to suggest it is also anything else. The concept of *Bodyscape photography* is to photograph a human body in such a way that at first glance it appears to either be something else, usually a landscape, or it is so well integrated into an actual landscape that only after further examination is it clear that much more of the scene than is initially evident is in fact part of a human body. Even when it becomes clear to the viewer that a human body has been photographed to create the work, there also remains the other reality that the body is used to depict.

Allan Teger is the person who coined the term *Bodyscape* to describe the [photographic works](http://bodyscapes.com/collections) he began creating in 1975 to illustrate the concept of two simultaneous realities that he was teaching in college psychology courses. [His bio at his page](http://bodyscapes.com/pages/about-us) describes what he means by *Bodyscape* in a definitive explanation. It seems to him to be a duality that is both human body and landscape at the same time without either excluding the other.

For some excellent examples of *Bodyscape photography*, please see *[Bodyscape Photography – 20 Brilliant Examples](http://designgrapher.com/bodyscape-photography-examples/)*, *[30 Creative Camouflaged Body-scape Photographs by Jean Paul Bourdier](http://webneel.com/30-creative-camouflaged-body-scape-photographs-jean-paul-bourdier)*, and *[Allan Teger’s Bodyscape Photographs](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/08/14/allan-teger-bodyscapes-nude-landscapes-photos_n_1775662.html?slideshow=true#gallery/244580/0)*.

Comment: It is interesting that the reference photos in "Bodyscape Photography – 20 Brilliant Examples" link are, save one, instantly recognizable as human bodies.

Comment: I wouldn't say that at all. Many of them at first glance could be mistaken for desert landscapes or abstract art. Some do have elements that look like the parts of a human body that they are, but much of the rest (that is ultimately seen to also be human) looks like other elements in the scene that are used to frame the disambiguated feet or hands.

Comment: @CoryTrese Also please notice the *or* in the middle of the sentence that describes as "... to photograph a human body in such a way that at first glance it appears to be something else, usually a landscape, **or** is so well integrated into an actual landscape that only after further examination is it clear that much more of the scene than is initially evident is in fact part of a human body." (I've just edited the second clause to address your concerns)

Comment: As addressed in the next paragraph, Teger himself describes it as having a duality: it is both human body and landscape at the same time without either excluding the other.